# need to update some text into website developed with twig silex symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig, silex

I have a website developed by someone else with Silex framework.
Now, I must change few words but have no idea about how to do it.
I identified the file where is stored the text, have twig extension, and I changed the text there but without any visible effect on my webpage!

It is a render or compile function involved into the process, should be performed a specific action in order to update website content with the new text from twig file?

Answer (score 1):

Search your codebase for `http_cache.cache_dir`. This is where your cache might be, delete that directory. If there is no cache directory it might be the case that your pages are cached in a reversed proxy like Varnish. Run `varnishadm "ban req.url ~ /"` to clear all cache in Varnish. (Varnish might run on another server.)

Answer (score 0):

Since Silex uses cache, your modifications may not have been taken in account, you have to reset the cache.

For this, you can manually delete everything in the cache folder, or you can run these to reinitialize the cache :

```
$app['twig']->clearCacheFiles();
$app['twig']->clearTemplateCache();
```

Comment: Can you give me the full path?
I wasn't able to find where is located app/cache/ folder.

Comment: It might be directly `/cache/`.

Comment: It looks like I don't have this cache folder?!